Azure Logic app (standard) connections are missing access policies
I've deployed two connections office365 and sharepointonline to be used with a Logic app (standard). Both connections are created through ARM template, along with the Logic app (standard). When I add the connectinos through a pipeline to the Logic app, it is coming up that it's missing access policies - I thought these were auto-generated?
Connection ARM template:
{
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
        "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
        "name": "[variables('connections_office365_name')]",
        "location": "[variables('primaryLocation')]",
        "tags": "[variables('tags')]",
        "kind": "V2",
        "properties": {
            "displayName": "Name",
            "statuses": [
                {
                    "status": "Connected"
                }
            ],
            "customParameterValues": {},
            "nonSecretParameterValues": {},
            "createdTime": "2024-03-26T09:34:43.4138095Z",
            "changedTime": "2024-04-04T20:52:07.4299297Z",
            "api": {
                "name": "office365",
                "displayName": "Office 365 Outlook",
                "description": "Microsoft Office 365 is a cloud-based service that is designed to help meet your organization's needs for robust security, reliability, and user productivity.",
                "iconUri": "[concat('https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/releases/v1.0.1676/1.0.1676.3617/', variables('connections_office365_name'), '/icon.png')]",
                "brandColor": "#0078D4",
                "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/',parameters('subscriptionId'),'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/uksouth/managedApis/', variables('connections_office365_name'))]",
                "type": "Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis"
            },
            "testLinks": [
                {
                    "requestUri": "[concat('https://management.azure.com:443/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('resourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/', variables('connections_office365_name'), '/extensions/proxy/testconnection?api-version=2016-06-01')]",
                    "method": "get"
                }
            ]
        }
      }

and then this is the connection.json file I am using to try add the connections to the Logic app (standard)
{
    "managedApiConnections": {
        "office365": {
            "api": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/@appsetting('WORKFLOWS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID')/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/@appsetting('WORKFLOWS_LOCATION_NAME')/managedApis/office365"
            },
            "authentication": {
                "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
            },
            "connection": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/@appsetting('WORKFLOWS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID')/resourceGroups/@appsetting('WORKFLOWS_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME')/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365"
            },
            "connectionRuntimeUrl": "@appsetting('OFFICE365_CONNECTIONURL')"
        }
}

Am i missing something?
I'm expecting the status' of the connections to be connected.

@thnswlkr did you authorize the connections after deployment?

@VivekVaibhavShandilya yeah, connections have been authorized

Are you creating logic apps locally?

@VivekVaibhavShandilya creating them through ARM templates to deploy to environments, connections are created within the same ARM template

Try creating a simple same logic app workflow in portal and see if it works or not? AFAIK access policy issue is related access,  this way you can confirm if issue is related to access or error is thrown only when deployed using ARM template.

Access policies are not auto-generated. You do need to include them in the template like this -
{
   "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections/accessPolicies",
   "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
   "name": "[concat(variables('connections_office365_name'),'/','<object-ID>')]",
   "location": "[variables('primaryLocation')]",
   "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', variables('connections_office365_name'))]"
   ],
   "properties": {
      "principal": {
         "type": "ActiveDirectory",
         "identity": {
            "objectId": "<object-ID>",
            "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]"
         }
      }
   }
}

where <object-ID> is the object ID for the Microsoft Entra identity.

As mentioned by @10p, Microsoft.Web/connections will only create API connections and will not automatically add access policies. According to the official doc Create and deploy single-tenant based logic app workflows with Azure Arc-enabled Logic Apps (Preview), you need to include the following resource definition for each managed API connection and provide the following information:

{
   "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections/accessPolicies",
   "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
   "name": "[concat('<connection-name>'),'/','<object-ID>')]",
   "location": "<location>",
   "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('connection_name'))]"
   ],
   "properties": {
      "principal": {
         "type": "ActiveDirectory",
         "identity": {
            "objectId": "<object-ID>",
            "tenantId": "<tenant-ID>"
         }
      }
   }
}

